# Images disappear after app released to appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, app-store

There is something very weird in my app after it has been released to the appstore.
Some of the UIImages i used are just missing and seen black from some reasons.
I have checked many times before in device and simulator and it appeared just fine.
Some notes:

1. I did drag the files and check COPY - the images are in the library for sure
2. Images DO appears in Copy Bundle Resources under Build Phases
3. I used these 2 lines in order to get the image:

> [UIImage imageNamed:@"email_icon.png"] and [UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"facebook_icon"]

And i have just noticed that the extensions of the images are PNG not png - maybe is that the reason?

Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: It is case sensitive, as you suspect. In the simulator, file access is not case sensitive. On a real device, the file system is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replicate this issue on your device?  If not I'd recommend deleting the current version from your device and redeploying. You may have cached images on your device which are not allowing you from seeing the issue.

Secondly, yes, filenames on the device are case sensitive.  Also make sure that you are properly naming the files and it is not simply a spelling mistake or change from an image name.

Per your line of code you are missing the file extension on the second image
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"email_icon.png"] and [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_icon"]`  <-- what type of file is facebook_icon?

Comment: Already tried few times to delete and deploy to my device and it WORKS everytime, the problem that is doesnt work in the appstore version.

both files are:
email_icon.PNG and facebook_icon.PNG
usually i dont put extension in the mehthod imageNamed and it works ok, thats why i left it like this but maybe i was wrong doing it?

thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to have a secondary device or a friend who you could possibly add their device to test on?  Additionally I'd make sure that the images are being included in your bundle so that Apple is getting all of your assets that they need.

Comment: Looks like its working after naming correctly, i will have to upload new version.
Thank you :)